# How to place text over dot line in blade template on Laravel and boostrap4

Tags: css, laravel, bootstrap-4

I have a small laravel project that pass variable `{{$docno}}` to blade template. Below is code in blade.

```
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="text-center">
                <span><strong>Medical Certify</strong></span>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix">
                <span class="float-left normal">Ref No..........</span>
                <span class="float-right normal" style="margin-top:-5px; position: relative">{{$docno}}</span>
                <span class="float-right normal">Doc no ............</span> 
            </div>  
        </div>
    </body>
```

My need is to place variable `$docno` on top of dotted at the right. But the above code does not work properly. Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: what is the problem here? be specific, show error log and controller code.

Comment: Dear  Sohel0415, There's no error, I need to place text variable over dotted line.

Comment: You could also wrap your variable in a span and then style with a dotted bottom border: `span {border-bottom: 2px dotted black; }`

Comment: Dear  rpm192. I'll try, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you want it to appear as if the text is filled in on the dotted line. A better solution might be to add a dotted line to the value. This way, you are sure the text is always correctly positioned.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="clearfix">
    <span class="float-left d-inline-block pr-3">Ref No. </span>
    <span class="float-left d-inline-block" style="border-bottom: 1px dotted">{{$docno}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Dear Jerodev, That's exactly I need. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of attempting to align the text with the line of dots, add a border to a span that you wrap your variable in.

```css
span {
  border-bottom: 2px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<p>Doc Number: <span>37249</span></p>
```

Comment: Dear rpm192, Your code work perperly. Thank you very much.